# Round upper corners for UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to round upper corners for `UITableView`. But Table view is not displaying. What is wrong here ?

// TableView setup

```
lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tv = UITableView()
        tv.delegate = self
        tv.dataSource = self
        tv.separatorStyle = .none
        tv.backgroundColor = .white
        tv.layer.masksToBounds = true
        tv.roundUpperCorners(radius: 12)
        return tv
    }()
```

// Round upper corners.

```
 func roundUpperCorners(radius: CGFloat) {
        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
```

Comment: You are not setting the frame of the table when you are trying to round the corners. Try to round the corners after setting the table's frame.

Comment: I'm setting constraints. Pinning top, bottom, left and right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working. Thanks to Fahri Azimov for mentioning "Try to round the corners after setting the table's frame".

I moved this line `tableView.roundUpperCorners(radius: 12)` into viewDidLayoutSubviews.

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        tableView.roundUpperCorners(radius: 12)
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

As per **@Fahri Azimov** comment you should set frame of your table view, first go with his comment. If still facing issue then use below code.

From my code,

```
myTblView.clipsToBounds = true
myTblView.layer.cornerRadius = 10 // Set As you want
myTblView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner,.layerMaxXMinYCorner]
```

NOTE : [maskedCorners](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/2877488-maskedcorners) new in iOS 11 you can read from official document.

Comment: What is the `maskedCorners` property? Is it some kind of extension? If so, you should provide the code, or give a reference to the library that contains it to be helpful.

Comment: @FahriAzimov Look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cacornermask?utm_source=Little%20Bites%20of%20Cocoa&utm_campaign=5e8e3ea5c8-EMAIL_CAMPAIGN_2017_06_16&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_2b6df83b4b-5e8e3ea5c8-114264253

Comment: is this possible to define the use of `maskedCorners`,  there no definition in apple api documentation

Comment: Ok, thanks for the edit, it's only available in iOS 11.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, the other solutions fail, when the tableview has bottomAnchor = 0 with the superview. The content of the tableview is clipped when you scroll down.

Answer (score 3):

```
extension UIView {
func roundCorners(_ corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = mask
}}
```

`yourView.roundCorners([.topLeft,.topRight], radius: 5)`

Comment: whats the difference b/w your answer and already asked in the question