# How to create tableview with rounded corners

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibezierpath, rounded-corners

I was trying to create rounded corner for tableview using *UIBezierPath* and its not working and so far the better way seems to be have the tableview inside a view and round the corner for the view rather than tableview.

Does anybody have a better way of doing it

Comment: can you share design screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round upper corners for UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46882750/round-upper-corners-for-uitableview)

Answer (score 7):

To round the `UITableView's` corners,

**1.** Make sure `UITableViewCell's` `clipToBounds` is `selected` in `Storyboard`.

**2.** Make sure `UITableView's` `clipToBounds` is `selected` in `Storyboard`.

[image]

**3.** Set `cornerRadius` value of `UITableView's` `layer`, i.e.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you need rounded corners for your table view rows check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049226/rounded-corners-in-a-uitableview-ios7)

For Objective-c:--

```
   cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
   cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

For Swift:--

```
cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

For whole tableview try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106861/round-corners-on-uitableview)

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

 self.tableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.6 alpha:1].CGColor;   
 self.tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
 self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
```

Comment: If I set corner radius to cell then corners of all the cells will be changed right

Comment: I want to round the corner of tableview not all the cells

Comment: Try the second one then self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 5; corner radius to tableview